# Android Content Provider Security Exception

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-securityexception

I am trying to open a PDF or Text file from my app with other reader application like Google Drive PDF viewer etc. But it is showing the following error.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.my.app.provider.GenericFileProvider from ProcessRecord{87fdcbb 31761:com.google.android.apps.docs/u0a37} (pid=31761, uid=10037) that is not exported from uid 10081
```

Manifest file:

```
<provider
        android:name="com.my.app.provider.GenericFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.my.package.name.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

provider_paths file:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ChatAdapterHelper.Document.getDocumentExtension(message.content));

String authority = AppContext.getAccess().getContext().getPackageName() + ".my.package.name.provider";

Uri fileUri = GenericFileProvider.getUriForFile(AppContext.getAccess().getContext(), authority, file);
Log.d("fileUri", "openDocument: fileUri " + fileUri);

intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, mimeType);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getString(R.string.open_file_with));

chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

AppContext.getAccess().getContext().startActivity(chooser);
```

SDK versions:

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27
```

I am trying to follow the procedure of using content provider explained in Android Developer website and other forum posts but can't get what is wrong here!

Comment: can you try to remove `chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` from your code and try again?

Comment: No luck here. 
Showing this error `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

Comment: To ensure `chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` is not root cause, can you try to move this code in Activity? And instead of `AppContext.getAccess().getContext()` simply use `startActivity(chooser);` ?

Comment: Sure... But it will take some time...

Comment: No problem. Let me know if it works

Comment: Tried this way. No progress. Same error showing after calling it directly from activity.

Comment: The `FLAG_GRANT_*_URI_PERMISSION` flags need to be set on the `Intent` passed into `createChooser()`; in your case, `intent`. Also, be aware that `setFlags()` will supersede any previous call to it. That is, the last call's flag(s) will replace any previous call's. You can combine multiple flags in one call with `|`, or use the `addFlags()` method with them individually. And do make sure to use `addFlags()` for `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on the `chooser` `Intent`, as the grant permission flag(s) will have been added to it also in `createChooser()`.

Comment: That's it. Thanks. My problem solved!

Comment: @MikeM. Can you please post this solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FLAG_GRANT_*_URI_PERMISSION` flags need to be set on the `Intent` passed into `createChooser()`; in this case, `intent`.

Also, be aware that `setFlags()` will supersede any previous call to it. That is, the last call's flag(s) will wholly replace any previous call's. You can combine multiple flags in one call with `|`, or use the `addFlags()` method with them individually. For example:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Alternatively:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Also, make sure to use `addFlags()` for the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on the `chooser` `Intent`, as the grant permission flags will have been added to that as well when it was constructed in the `createChooser()` method.

```
chooser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```